# Where do packages get installed in debian systems?

Tags: debian, package-management, packages

I recently installed expect on my Ubuntu system and cannot find the example code that is supposed to come with it. I searched /usr/lib /usr/bin/lib /lib...no luck. I guess it's about time I learned how these things are organized.

Your help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Err...you wouldn't want example code in `*/lib` as those directories are for libraries in the *"link-to-your-program"* sense of the word.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Example code on Debian-based systems like Ubuntu is usually stored in `/usr/share/doc/<package name>/examples`.

For more information about what goes in which directory, check out the [Filesystem Hierarchy Standard](http://refspecs.linuxfoundation.org/FHS_3.0/fhs/index.html), which Ubuntu follows for the most part.

Answer (score 9):

Use this command

```
dpkg -L {package}
```

Generally there are two tools for managing packages in debian systems. **apt-get** and **dpkg**.

More information in these links :

http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/linux-debian-package-management-cheat-sheet.html

<strike>http://www.cyberciti.biz/howto/question/linux/apt-get-cheat-sheet.php</strike>

<strike>http://www.cyberciti.biz/howto/question/linux/dpkg-cheat-sheet.php</strike>

Cheat sheet for both **apt-get** and **dpkg**:
https://blog.packagecloud.io/eng/2015/03/30/apt-cheat-sheet/

Answer (score 4):

`dpkg -L expect` will list the `/var/lib/dpkg/info/expect.list` file for the package which lists the full path of each of the package's files.  You may want to pipe it to `less` so you can read it.

`man hier` should give you a description of the file system hierarchy used by Debian.  The maintainers tend to be quite religious about following it and will often create symlinks to directories to allow programs that don't follow it to work within their structure.

Documentation goes in `/usr/share/doc/<package-name>`, so expect's documentation will be found in `/usr/share/doc/expect`.  There may be multiple `example` subdirectories below that, along with other directories which may contain runnable code. man pages go elsewhere, but can be found with the command `man -k expect`.

For other packages replace `expect` in the above commands with the package name.